# The best jquery option for firing a function when an input is selected

Tags: jquery

This is a fairly trivial question but there a lots of ways this could be done using click functions etc.

My question is, when an input is clicked and selected...

```
<textarea name="input_3" id="input_5_3" class="textarea medium" tabindex="3" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

So when the above element is selected, I would like to run this animate functions...

```
$('#input_5_3').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '150px'
  }, 500, function() {

  });
});
```

Now the above function will work to an extent, but is the some way or technique to toggle this element when focused/active? Instead of using click

Thanks
Josh

---

Addition to maximos answer...

```
$('#input_5_3').on('click focus', function () {
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '150px'
        }, 500, function () {

        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '40px'
        }, 500, function () {

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: toggle how exactly, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/86aCs/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Use "bind" or "on"

```
$('#input_5_3').on('click focus', function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '150px'
    }, 500, function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried your idea above using a toggle fuction similar to how I use it in hover but is not working? I've added my code above.

Comment: @Joshc `.on()` does not have a toggle method like hover

Comment: @Joshc, Spokey says true. What would you like to do?

Comment: @maximkou someone comment as comment above with what I need to do thank you